# Какой формулой можно рассчитывать итог комбинации в покере?

Tags: python, python-3.x

К примеру у нас есть стол с картами:

```
['3♠', '5♥', 'A♣', '4♦', 'K♥']
```

И наши карты:

```
['5♣', '5♦']
```

Комбинация `сет` из 5, как это рассчитывать?

Или же такую комбинацию:

```
['3♠', '3♥', '3♣', '4♦', 'K♥']
```

Наши:

```
['9♣', '6♦']
```

Тоже `сет` из 3. Ну и другие комбинации, есть может бы уже готовые решения, или модули?

Comment: Не очень ясно что нужно расчитать. "рассчитывать итог комбинации в покере?" имеется ввиду шанс сета? Или что? Просто у вас есть уже ривер в примере и ваша рука, что сделать то надо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def is_set(a, b):
    cards = list(map(lambda x: x[0], a + b))
    for i in cards:
        if cards.count(i) == 3:
            return True
    return False


a = ['3♠', '5♥', 'A♣', '4♦', 'K♥']
b = ['5♣', '5♦']
print(is_set(a, b))  # True
```

Comment: спасибо большое, это ваше собственное решине? Или образец откуда-то и есть другие расчеты комбинаций

Comment: На здоровье. Да, мое

Comment: могу ли я у вас заказать все остальные вычисления за сумму? Если это возможно конечно

Comment: Пытайтесь делать сами, если не выйдет форум поможет.